# Choosing an input signal based on whether a driver signal is floating

Tags: audio, analog, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I have three inputs: an analog microphone signal (M+), a push-to-talk (PTT) signal, and a ground (G). The PTT signal is connected to G when the button is depressed and M+ should be carried, and is floating when not connected. M+ is always live and referenced to G.

I want two outputs, namely the microphone and ground, with the PTT behaving as expected. I believe what I therefore want is something along the line of the following setup:

- Output ground connected to G
- Output microphone as the output of an analog SPDT multiplexer (e.g. the Maxim DG419DJ); the two signal inputs being M+ and G.

However, I'm not sure how to drive the multiplexer. PTT is either the same as G, or floating compared to G, but multiplexers seem to expect (sensibly, I admit) a voltage difference in their driver inputs.

I am, as you may well have guessed, not particularly au fait with electronics, so my question is essentially--how can I make this work? Is an analog multiplexer even the thing I'm looking for?

Comment: Add a pullup resistor from PTT to +V (3.3 or 5 depending on the analog mux). Connect M+ to the MUX input selected when SEL = 0 (and G to the other.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplexer will require extra circuitry around it and will be a bit of a hassle.

Maybe go for a more brute force but robust solution: a relay.
It's just a mechanical contact so there's no concern about signal voltage levels, which a multiplexer solution would have to contend with.

Relays are about $2 and come in different coil voltages: 5V, 9V, 12V are common.

For example you could use a 9V relay and 9V battery: apply 9V across the coil and the switch closes.

Relay parameters to be aware of:

-you want a "non-latching" relay

-a single-pole single-throw (SPST) relay is fine, but using half of a DPDT is fine too

-switch contacts are often labelled (N.O. = normally open, and N.C. = normally closed).

"Normally" in this context is the switch state when coil is not energized.
So in the schematic below the MIC_OUT net is connected to the "normally open" pin of the relay.

Note the relay will make a small acoustic click when toggled. If anybody complains tell them it's a feature: it lets them know they pressed the button.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFgUQp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>